# Dictionary in VBA is created with empty key value pair

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

After creating a new dictionary:

```
Dim teams as Dictionary
Set teams = New Dictionary
```

I noticed that it already contains empty key - value pair (teams.Count returns value of 1).
How can I prevent this from happening or delete this pair? Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Mine performs well. Are you referencing correct Microsoft Scripting Runtime?

Comment: Yes I am. Even after removing empty pair, it was always re-created after I added first valid pair. The funny thing is that today the dictionary works fine. Guess the simple reboot and nights rest solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referencing the same `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` dictionary `scrrun.dll` as me - Excel 2010.

[image]

Then the below code returns `0` as the `.Count` of items after creation with no manipulation.

```
Sub SD()
    Dim teams As Dictionary
    Set teams = New Dictionary
    Debug.Print teams.Count
End Sub
```

I wouldn't know the reason why your dictionary returns `1`, however I think a workaround it would be to simply use the `.RemoveAll` method of the `Dictionary` object

```
Sub SD()
    Dim teams As Dictionary
    Set teams = New Dictionary
    teams.RemoveAll
    Debug.Print teams.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: I would appreciate a comment from the person who down voted my answer

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I see this behavior, and after executing RemoveAll I still have 1 key/value pair of empty/empty.

Comment: Is it because VB6 uses 1 as the base of arrays rather than 0 like most of other languages?

Comment: I don't think so. See my answer below. I believe the reason that some people experience this and some don't is that the people with the problem are using the Watch Window with their dictionary. Once I removed my Watch and inspected the dictionary via the Immediate window, I saw it correctly had 0 Items.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same experience and solved it.

I had a Watch expression set for a value in the dictionary. Somehow this kept the empty key/value pair in the dictionary (or kept readding it).

Removing the watch(es) and stepping through the code I now see the dictionary does not have the Empty/Empty item any longer.

Comment: Great answer. Confirmed that I can replicate this.

Comment: Cool. In this case my answer is somehow invalid. If the Op accepts your answer I will remove mine.

Comment: This is definitely the issue in my case as well. I agree, remove all watches on the dictionary.

Comment: GAH. Thank you for posting this - confirmed still an issue.