VBA: Class Get procedure adds an item to a Dictionary (for unknown reason)
I have a class file_management, it contains a nested dictionary - sheet_names (plus corresponding private p_sheet_names). Within a loop, I am trying to verify if a sheet already exists using a formula SheetExists (note: the formula is most likely not the issue. This malfunction happens for other solutions as well). I pass a sheet name argument to the SheetExists using a reference from a nested dictionary:
file_management.sheet_names(curr)(file_name_replacement)
XX_Bool - is a random variable just to present example here
Verifying if a sheet exists:
Dim XX_bool As Boolean
XX_bool = SheetExists(file_management.sheet_names(curr)(file_name_replacement), WB_Edit)

this initiates a Get procedure:
Public Property Get sheet_names() As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set sheet_names = p_sheet_names
End Property

at the entry point both sheet_names and p_sheet_names have 28 elements. However, when the code exits the procedure at end property, my sheet_names somehow ends up with 29 items.
Questions:

Why is this excessive element added?
How can I prevent adding this item?

Already tried:
Honestly I'm lost, I think the Get property should not add any elements and I have no idea why it does. The only thing I came up with was altering the Get procedure for it to not Set the sheet_name (see below) but this did not work:
Public Property Get sheet_names() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim tempDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant

    ' Copy each item to the new dictionary
    For Each key In p_sheet_names.Keys
        tempDict.Add key, p_sheet_names(key)
    Next key

    Set sheet_names = tempDict

    '?not sure? Below caused issues with adding excessive values to dict
    'Set sheet_names = p_sheet_names
    
End Property

I've also tried to verify if a worksheet exists using below code. This also failed:
Dim ws_temp1 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
        Set ws_temp1 = cWS.ws_Main.Parent.Worksheets(file_management.sheet_names(curr)(file_name_replacement))
On Error GoTo 0
        
If ws_temp1 Is Nothing Then
    cWS.ws_Main.Name = file_management.sheet_names(curr)(file_name_replacement)
Else
    cWS.ws_Main.Name = "Temp Sheet"
End If

NOTE:
A Sheet's existence I am verifying is false - the sheet does not exist when the issue is happening
EDIT:
Immediate window check:
?file_management.sheet_names("Reporting").exists(file_name_replacement)
False


Please share the code how you fill p_sheet_names. You are saying it is a nested dictionary, right?

@Storax the p_sheet_names is filled using bit complexed logic referring to multiple objects in multiple classes.  Would prefer not to share the full logic. Nevertheless I am 100% sure there are 28 items in the p_sheet_names when I call the get procedure. Would that be enough as a confirmation?

In that case please try to provide an example and code where one can reproduce the issue. Otherwise it is really difficult to help, at least for me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I managed to fix the issue by breaking a reference to my nested dictionary. Instead of calling the SheetExists by
Dim XX_bool As Boolean
XX_bool = SheetExists(file_management.sheet_names(curr)(file_name_replacement), WB_Edit)

I've done:
        Dim x
        Set x = file_management.sheet_names("Reporting")
        
        Dim XX_bool As Boolean
        XX_bool = x.Exists(file_name_replacement)

This solution worked for me.
Thank you for your time spent looking into the issue.

Anyhow, does the solution implies what was the issue in a first place? This still bothers me

As said, I do not know because it is difficult to analyze without an example where one can reproduce the issue. I agree that Property Get sheet_names should not change the number of elements.

Using the Watch window with a dictionary can cause items to be added to the dictionary being watched. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41858402/478884

Seems like not only Watch window but any type of ByRef reference can add an empty item. For me, especially with nested dictionaries

Code seems to be breaking frequently on references like: dictionary(key)(lower_key)
